# How to add +1 to a number through PHP?

Tags: php, explode

I am Having the data like:

```
$aa ="msg_1";
```

I want to add +1 at the end of string after doing the explode operation like the following:

```
$nwMsg =explode("_",$aa);
    $inMsg =number_format($nwMsg[1])+1;
    $finStr =$nwMsg[0].'_'.$inMsg;
```

After This i want to form the string again and repeating  the same process again but it is increasing  up to `"10"` after that it is not increasing...

Comment: `$inMsg = number_format($nwMsg[1] + 1);`

Comment: Define not working, please. What does the value contain?

Comment: I'm surprised none of the below answers use `++$nsMsg[1]` per the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php)

Comment: it is showing the same value as 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function add_one($string) {
    preg_match_all("/[a-zA-Z]+_\d+/", $string, $matches);
    $elements = $matches[0];
    $last = $elements[count($elements)-1];
    $components = explode("_", $last);
    $newnum = $components[1] + 1;
    return $string . $components[0] . "_" . $newnum;
}
echo add_one("msg_1"); // prints "msg_1msg_2"
echo add_one("msg_1msg_2msg_3msg_4msg_5msg_6msg_7msg_8msg_9"); // prints "msg_1msg_2msg_3msg_4msg_5msg_6msg_7msg_8msg_9msg_10"
```

Comment: i wanted it like auto increment

Comment: @SivaG You said it is not working but now you want auto increment. Please be certain about what you are asking for.

Comment: i want it like "msg_1........msg_10..................msg_100.....msg_1000..........."

Comment: @SivaG Do you want to chain them together as a string?

Comment: s u r right... but it is not having any limit...

Comment: this is fine but i dont want limit........

Comment: @SivaG Give me a sec. Let me write you a function for this.

Answer (score 3):

You should put the `+1` inside the `number_format` call, not after it.

EDIT: If you just want `$nwMsg[1]` to be treated as a number, just adding 1 to it will work fine, since `+` is a numerical operator.

Answer (score 1):

```
$nwMsg =explode("_",$aa);
$inMsg =number_format($nwMsg[1] +1) ;
$finStr =$nwMsg[0].'_'.$inMsg;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$aa= "msg_1";
$new_string= explode("_", $aa);
$new_aa= $new_string[0] ."10";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong

```
$inMsg =number_format($nwMsg[1])+1;
```

This is how it is done

```
$inMsg =number_format($nwMsg[1]+1);
```

Comment: same value showing Guys..as 10

Comment: @SivaG What exactly u want ?

Comment: i want it like "msg_1........msg_10..................msg_100.....msg_1000..........."

Comment: You want it to print infinitely ???

Comment: Dude atleast there must be a limit to print till a desired no... If u want infinite , than using infinite loop will never end ur program

Comment: dude...i will tell the process it is like sending a message with this group id so it wont have a limit know.............

Answer (score 0):

```
$nwMsg =explode("_",$aa);
$inMsg =$nwMsg[1] +1 ;
$finStr =$nwMsg[0].'_'.$inMsg;
```

You will get the result with out using number_format.

Comment: no the same value i am getting 10

Answer (score 0):

One more thing, which can lead to errors and you need to take care - because you want to add two numbers, first make sure that you convert `$nwMsg[1]` into number (integer or float, it depends):

```
$nwMsg =explode("_",$aa);
    $inMsg =number_format((int)$nwMsg[1]+1);
    $finStr =$nwMsg[0].'_'.$inMsg;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a different solution:

```
function add($matches) {
    return ++$matches[0];
}

$new = preg_replace_callback("(\d+)", "add", $aa);
```